# unknow the shape of numpy array and error while predicting the model

Tags: arrays, numpy, machine-learning, keras, machine-translation

after i trained my mode i wanted to test but it was hopeless but i found away

this is the weights of my model

[image]

and i do not know the shape of my array in order to use the prediction the shape of input and the shape of model should be the same

i tried this

```
v = np.array(range(10), dtype=str).reshape(2, 5)
v[0, 0] = "you are stronger "
predicted_output = model.predict(v)
```

but though the error which is :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to
>   have shape (4,) but got array with shape (5,)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data - post the code/data itself. In any case, your question doesn't have enough information for anyone to answer.

Comment: What do you mean with "I do not know the shape of my array". It seems plausible that scikit-learn wants the arrrays to be of same size. We cannot assess where the problem occurs without knowing the relevant aspects of your data and code

Comment: A more succinct elaboration of your problem would be helpful here, but if what you're struggling with is with input dimension, you can easily check that information with `model.summary()` or  `plot_model` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model). This saves you from the hassle of trying to figure out your model's structure from its weight, which is often just a huge numpy array as shown.